# how to set up the temp dir path in Python?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am using the latest `Anaconda` Python distribution and I wonder how can I tell Python to unzip/store all the temporary output to a specific folder (instead of the `/tmp` directory).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do the [tempdir or tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) fit your needs?

Comment: what I need is making sure whenever Python writes some temporary output somewhere, it is on a directory I defined (say `/mydrive/alternativeTMP`). Space is super limited in `tmp` and I need to avoid it

Comment: which actions are writing to `/tmp`?

Comment: well I guess opening a `csv.gz` file, or decompressing some archive?

Comment: I don't believe Python explicitly has the `-j` flag like `unzip` does in bash, that is what you are looking for correct?

Comment: thanks for helping out. no, I am looking for the R equivalent of setting up a `tmp` dir in Python. For instance, opening a compressed csv with Pandas `read_csv('myfile.csv.gz')` will necessarily decompress the file somewhere. I want to control where this is done.

Comment: Is mounting /tmp on a different volume out of the question?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible to do in pure python

Answer (score 4):

I found something interesting in the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) page. The function `gettempdir` gets the temporary folder from the following environment variable:

> - The directory named by the TMPDIR environment variable.
> - The directory named by the TEMP environment variable.
> - The directory named by the TMP environment variable.
> - A platform-specific location:
>
>   1. On Windows, the directories C:\TEMP, C:\TMP, \TEMP, and \TMP, in that order.
>   2. On all other platforms, the directories /tmp, /var/tmp, and /usr/tmp, in that order.
> - As a last resort, the current working directory.

Maybe you can overwrite one of this variable.

Comment: i cant believe it actually worked! used TMPDIR to override the temp dir some 3rd party python cmd